# lifetime of the token at present time

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have a JWT with the following payload:

```
{
  "id": "394a71988caa6cc30601e43f5b6569d52cd7f6df",
  "jti": "394a71988caa6cc30601e43f5b6569d52cd7f6df",
  "iss": "issuer_id",
  "aud": "client_id",
  "sub": "user_id",
  "exp": 1483711650,
  "iat": 1483708050,
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "scope": "onescope twoscope"
}
```

iat : issued at in epoch time

exp:  expiry in epoch time

I want to check lifetime of the token at present.

Can someone please suggest bestway of doing this?

Comment: If am getting your question right, then simply subtract iat value from current timestamp that's your value. You can then convert to date if you need.

Comment: you subtract `iat` from `exp` and then you get the number of milliseconds the token is valid (its lifetime). if you want it in hours you simply multiply : `(exp-iat)*1000*60*60` - sorry didn't get the *"at present"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get current epoch time (here instant is from java.time.Instant package )

```
long currentTimeEpocSec = Instant.now().getEpochSecond()
```

then subtract expires time with current time ,it gives duration in seconds.

```
 long duration = expiresAt - currentTimeEpocSec;
```

to get in seconds

```
long durationInMinutes = duration / 60;
```